# MongoDB and MVC model variables

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I'm coming from CodeIgniter/MySQL to Laravel/MongoDB.

For example a User class with different variables by platform:

I website use the variables:

- id
- name
- browser_kind

In mobile app use the variables:

- id
- name
- ios_version

Considering this cases, in my model should I have both vars?

```
<?php
    class user{
        public $id;
        public $name;
        public $browser_kind;
        public $ios_version;
    }
?>
```

What about the NoSQL benefit that don't need a pre-defined structure? How to use this in the models?

Answer (score 1):

Just because Mongo doesn't need a schema, you still need to model your models. One of the biggest benefits would be that you can change your data models without Mongo hanging up on you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just store the `null` of either `browser_kind` or `ios_version` as well in the same document. The reason for this is for future expansion. IOS does support Firefox and Opera Mini etc so with that in mind I would recommend you store the entire schema together.

However, since you seem to have two kinds of static schema here I would suggest you think about not storing both the `browser_kind` and `ios_version` within the same document as one or the other being `null`.

Since the two schemas are never gong to overlap (in what we know about your scenario) you will instead just use a fair amount of precious space depending on how many documents are in the collection. This is because MongoDB does not compress its files currently.

It also seems like these fields would never be `null` where they are needed, i.e. `browser_kind` and all other fields would never be `null` in a document that needs them for a non-mobile user.

As such I would keep the model the way you got it but I would use a function like `array_filter` to strip fields you don't want to save.

Of course, this is a problem, you are using a framework which abstracts all of this logic to a place you probably can't get to unless you do a lot yourself. Considering this you could make two class that abstract from a single `user` class, one that defines `browser_kind` and one that defines `ios_version` but then this starts to add weight to your application.

So that gives you a few options there and things to think about.